# Mongodb correct pagination

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework

https://mongoplayground.net/p/lDfJhiqumx-

In case anyone needs an easy way to find a way to test it.

What would be the ideal way to get the total elements and then using limit and skip. This is only used to get the amount for pages for a Pagination Material UI element.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "message": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b5a"
        },
        "author": "Dr. Jameson",
        "subject": "Lab Results Uploaded",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
        "timestamp": {
          "$date": "2021-04-12T05:51:03.793Z"
        },
        "lastDateRead": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b52"
        },
        "author": "Dr. Jameson",
        "subject": "Lab Results Uploaded2",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
        "timestamp": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:50:03.793Z"
        },
        "lastDateRead": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b5b"
        },
        "author": "Dr. Johnson",
        "subject": "Lab Results",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
        "timestamp": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        },
        "lastDateRead": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "message": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b5a"
        },
        "author": "Dr. Jameson",
        "subject": "Lab Results Uploaded",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
        "timestamp": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        },
        "lastDateRead": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "609cbe47a45b594af4bc6b5b"
        },
        "author": "Dr. Johnson",
        "subject": "Lab Results",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sceleri...",
        "timestamp": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        },
        "lastDateRead": {
          "$date": "2021-05-13T05:51:03.793Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$message"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "message.author": {
            $regex: "Dr. Jo"
          }
        },
        {
          "message.subject": {
            $regex: "La"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "message.timestamp": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      message: {
        $push: "$message"
      },
      
    }
  },
  
])
```

Comment: do you just want to paginate array, or root documents?

Comment: What I want is to paginate the inner array after I find the id=1. So I can pass back the total amount and the limit amount for the array. The total amount is all of the inner values that match filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you can select any one that suitable as per your requirement,

Sample pagination variables:

```
var skip = 0, limit = 3;
```

**Using `$slice`:**

- instead of `$skip` and `$limit` you can use `$slice` for array and `$size` to get total messages

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "1" } },
  { $unwind: "$message" },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "message.author": { $regex: "Dr. Jo" } },
        { "message.subject": { $regex: "La" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "message.timestamp": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      message: { $push: "$message" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalCount: { $size: "$message" },
      message: { $slice: ["$message",  skip, limit] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9QUJjJvEi1x)

---

**Using `$facet`, `$skip` and`$limit`:**

- `$facet` to separate result for count and messages
- `$count` to get total count of messages
- `$skip` and limit to paginate result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "1" } },
  { $unwind: "$message" },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "message.author": { $regex: "Dr. Jo" } },
        { "message.subject": { $regex: "La" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "message.timestamp": -1 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      totalCount: [{ $count: "totalCount" }],
      result: [
        { $skip: skip },
        { $limit: limit }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uxQaQkvFUVq)